# Simple java synchronization question

Tags: java, synchronized

In Groovy code something simple:
    #!/usr/bin/env groovy

```
public class test {
  boolean val
  def obj=new Object()

  def dos() {
    val=false
    Thread.start() {
      synchronized(obj) {
    val=true
    obj.notifyAll()
      }
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    synchronized(obj) {
      while (!val) {
    obj.wait()
      }
    }
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    def t=new test()
    t.dos()
  }
}
```

---

Ok, here is my problem in more detail.

Thread (A) 
start an action in a separate thread, then wait for its completion
-- OK THIS IS NOT EXACTLY TRUE OTHERWISE COULD USE thread.join(). This
Thread actually starts a task that then signals methodOne eventually

Thread (B)
we get a signal when action is completed

```
class A {
   private boolean finished

   public synchronized void methodOne() {
       finished=true;
       notifyAll();
   } 

   public void methodTwo() {
       new ThreadThatCallsMethodOneWhenDone().start();
       synchronized(this) {
           while (!finished) {
                 wait();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Is this code okay or am I still running into potential problems? What's a better way to solve?

Misha

---

I was wondering, which is correct:

Option One

```
class A {
   public void methodOne() {
       synchronized(this) {
           modifyvalue
           notifyAll()
       }
   }

   public void methodTwo() {
       while (valuenotmodified) {
           synchronized(this) {
              wait()
           }
       }
   }
```

Option Two

```
class A {
   public void methodOne() {
       modifyvalue
       synchronized(this) {
           notifyAll()
       }
   }

   public void methodTwo() {
       while (valuenotmodified) {
           synchronized(this) {
              wait()
           }
       }
   }
```

and why?

Comment: 21 questions, 3 accepted answers.  Have they all really been that bad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that both are dangerous because your `valuenotmodified` check is performed without synchronisation. So, there is no telling what happens if `methodOne` modifies the value while `methodTwo` is in process of verifying whether it has changed.

And I see no difference between your two "options". Both have this potential problem.

Comment: Addtional for the OP, Its worth nothing that if you notifyAll() before wait(), the wait() can wait forever. This can happen in your examples.

Answer (score 0):

All access to "value" should be synchronized:

```
class A {
   public void methodOne() {
       synchronized(this) {
           modifyvalue
           notifyAll()
       }
   }

   public void methodTwo() {
       synchronized(this) {
           if (valuenotmodified) {
              wait()
           }
       }
   }

}
```

Note that this is equivalent to:

```
class A {
   public synchronized void methodOne() {
       modifyvalue
       notifyAll()
   }

   public synchronized void methodTwo() {
       if (valuenotmodified) {
          wait()
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems like this are better handled by the concurrency library, first released in 1998, it became part of JDK 5 in 2004.  I suggest you learn how to use these as they are usually much easier to use and understand than the notify/notifyAll/wait constructs.

In your case you could use [Condition](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)  In its javadoc it comments

> Condition factors out the Object
>   monitor methods (wait, notify and
>   notifyAll) into distinct objects to
>   give the effect of having multiple
>   wait-sets per object, by combining
>   them with the use of arbitrary Lock
>   implementations. Where a Lock replaces
>   the use of synchronized methods and
>   statements, a Condition replaces the
>   use of the Object monitor methods.